# Matlab live script translation to latex within latex

Tags: formatting, matlab

Matlab has its own way to format text inside an *.m file --- if you open that *.m file as a live script it would format the whole-line-comments as text (see example). For this there are a set of simple rules to follow when you are writing your Matlab code. I would like to ask if there's any way to translate the Matlab formatting to latex, within latex (e.g. translate `*text*` as `\textbf{text}`, or `\begin{itemize} \item text \end{itemize}` when finding `%* text`).

The example below is the code in a file named `example.m` , if you open it as a live script in Matlab you get the outcome in the jpeg, and if you export it to latex it would do the job. I want to avoid the export step since I'm constantly editing the *.m files. Listings won't do the job since it would require to write latex code inside the *.m files and the formatting will not be recognized by Matlab.

My Idea is to create a package that let you input the *.m file and recognizes the different ways of formatting text.

```
%% example *This is the title for this example*
    % Some explanation for the objetive of the code. The formtting rules of matlab are quite simple. To write equations you can use basic latex:  ($\pi +\frac{a}{b^2}$) 
    %
    %% *Itemize list*
    % 
    % * x1 : first input
    % * x2 : second input
    %% 
    % How to insert an enumerated list
    %% 
    % # number 1 in our test
    % # final number
    %% 
    % How would I underline? or *bold *or _italic_
    function [y1,y2]= example(x1, x2)
    %% *Inputs*
        y1 = x1; % This is a comment shown in greem
        y2 = x2;

    %% *Some more nonsensical code*
        A(1) = x1;
        A(2) = x1;
        A(3) = y1;
        A(4) = y2;
    %% First Order Conditions
    % Consumption is an input when the zlb does not bind, but defined by the Euler 
    % equation when it does.
        if x1>x2
            c = x1^2;
            R = 1;
        else
            c = x2;
            R = y1; 
        end
    end
```

[image: MATLAB live script formatting]

Comment: Do you already know that Matlab’s publish() function can output LaTeX directly, and this can be customised if you edit the XSLT stylesheet used? This might be a more direct way to typeset whole Matlab files in the way you’re suggesting.

Comment: Thanks @WillRobertson , I might end up settling for something like this... The problem with publishing is that you have to re-publish once you have changed the code and you depend on MATLAB to do it. If I knew I was going to do it once or twice, that would be fine (maybe there's some way to do this automatically once you save), but I find a waste of time going back and forth.

Comment: NFP — that’s a good point. Depending on how much you wanted to automate this it should be possible to set up a make system or similar to rerun publish() as needed from the command line before typesetting the document. See (kind of): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657005/matlab-running-an-m-file-from-command-line